# NSURLConnection : Bad url problem

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, special-characters

It seems that the NSURLConnection have problems with handling æ,ø,å. And the webservice I'm trying to connect to do not handle that I convert them to UTF8 chars.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more information explicitly about the problems you encountered, the URL used, etc. There're many ways URL loading fails, and we're not psychics !

Answer (score 5):

If you have some special characters in you url string you might have to convert these characters to percent escapes using

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`
```

method and use the result later when working with NSURLs